# Roslyn crashes when I try to run a script

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have this Program class:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RoslynExperiment
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = ComputeAsync("1+2");
            Console.WriteLine(result.Result);
        }

        private static async Task<int> ComputeAsync(string formula)
        {
            return await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<int>(formula);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I call ComputeAsync, I get this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Inner Exception
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Why would I be getting this exception when I try to execute my script? How can I fix it?

Comment: I'd suggest showing how you run it.

Comment: How I run it? I press F5 in Visual Studio... am I missing something in your suggestion?

Comment: I was confused by the term "script", which led me to believe that perhaps it wasn't a regular application. I assumed that you were running something like [C# script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt614271.aspx) from the command line. I'm not particularly familiar with C# script beyond "it exists", so it was as good a guess as any :)

Comment: Hmm... What's really confusing is that I get the error on the call to ComputeAsync, not inside the function where I actually try to run the script...

Comment: For some reason I have a phantom reference to System.Runtime in my project that I can't delete; it shows up as a blue icon with connected shapes rather than the regular black icon. If I double click this reference it says it's not built yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a documented issue with Visual Studio and .Net. Try changing your target framework to [netstandard2.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/160).

Or, you can try adding the following to your .csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Legacy2CPSWorkaround" Version="1.0.0">
    <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I don't think changing a non-library program to .NET Standard would work. The other bit might though :)

Comment: I tried adding the ItemGroup to my project file, but it didn't help. How do I change my framework to .NET Standard? That option isn't available from the dropdown in project properties... plus I would like to be able to run scripts on .NET Framework!

Comment: I realized I can just create a .NET Standard class library with the scripting code and reference it from my main project :)

Comment: @ekolis Awesome! Good work figuring it out when none of us could.

Comment: @jamesfdearborn You pointed me in the right direction by suggesting .NET Standard! :)

Comment: Hmm, this won't work for me though because I need to sandbox my scripts in an AppDomain, which isn't supported in .NET Standard....